# asyncio hangs up at 99%

Tags: python, asynchronous, python-asyncio

The following site status-checking script keeps getting stuck at around 99%.

Timeout has been assigned as None to mitigate this, but the problem recurs nevertheless.

What is causing the script to fail at the end, and how can I make it so that Python can know when asyncio is stuck and do something about it?

```
import aiohttp, asyncio, platform, requests, re
from aiohttp import ClientSession, TCPConnector
import asyncio
from operator import contains
from tqdm import tqdm as tqdm
from tqdm.asyncio import tqdm as asyncProgress
from requests import Session
session = Session()

internet_archive = "https://web.archive.org/cdx/search/cdx?url=twitter.com/iamcardib/status&matchType=prefix&filter=statuscode:200&mimetype:text/html&from=20220302"

cdx = requests.get(internet_archive).text

urls = re.findall(r'https?://twitter\.com/(?:#!/)?\w+/status/\d+', cdx)


async def CheckSiteStatus(url, session: ClientSession, Sem: asyncio.Semaphore):
    
    async with Sem:
        async with session.get(url) as resp:
            return resp.real_url, resp.status
        
    
async def StatusCheck(links_list):
    statuses = []
    timeout = aiohttp.ClientTimeout(total=None)
    async with ClientSession(timeout=timeout) as session:
        Sem = asyncio.Semaphore(15)
        statuses = await asyncProgress.gather(*(CheckSiteStatus(u, session, Sem) for u in links_list))
    return statuses


if platform.system() == 'Windows':
    asyncio.set_event_loop_policy(asyncio.WindowsSelectorEventLoopPolicy())


end_list = asyncio.run(StatusCheck(urls))
```

Comment: Why are you setting the timeout to `None` when you want your request to time out?

Comment: Without setting timeout to `None`, `asyncio.TimeoutError` is raised from `None`. Someone had the same error, and an [answerer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69549556/18431610) suggested to equal timeout to `None`, which removed the `TimeoutError` but introduced the new problem in the original post.

Comment: `TimeoutError` being raised is not an error, it's your timeout happening. You need to catch it and handle it. Either where it happens in `CheckSiteStatus` or you can pass `return_exceptions=True` to `gather` (not sure if this is supported by the wrapper you're using).